# Azure Clickonce publishing

Tags: wpf, azure

we are working on a WPF application which we want to publish as a click once smart client application.

We are able to publish the application on local machine using Visual Studio 2012 and configured it in IIS.

Now we want to upload the published smart client installer to windows Azure Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8. We cannot upload the locally published components as the URL configuration in the manifest and deployment file is that of local server. We tried to edit the entries using text editor but once we do the editing the files become unused and it shows xml parsing error when we try to install from the location.

we tried to publish the application direct to the Virtual Machine but it shows an error as Front Page Extension is needed in IIS. We tried to find Front Page extension but couldn't find an version for IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012.

Can any one help us to publish the application in Azure Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having has nothing to do with Azure per se.

In the first case (of editing the XML files), you can do that but it's best to use MageUI to do the edit, because you can then re-sign the manifests. If you just edit the files, it messes up the security on them, and they will not work (as you have found). If you want to edit them with a text editor, you can do that, but then you must re-sign them (using mage); you can create a script to change the installation URL.

Or you can use MageUI. You need to do it in this order:

1. Open the application manifest in the versioned folder and then save it, re-signing it with your signing certificate.
2. Open the deployment manifest (yourapp.application) in the top deployment folder. Change the Start Folder to be the right Installation URL. Go to the "Application Reference" tab and re-select the application manifest in the versioned folder. (I know, it hasn't changed, but trust me, you have to do this.) Save this manifest and sign it with your signing certificate.
3. Copy the deployment manifest from the top folder to the versioned folder. It's always good to keep a copy, so you can go backwards a version if you need to.

NOW you can copy the files to your VM and they will work fine.

In the second case, the Front Page Extensions are required if you are using HTTP to publish the application, yet they are no longer available past about Windows Server 2008(?). So don't use HTTP. Use FTP. Set the publish file location using FTP, like ftp://myserver.mycompany.com/myfolder and set the Installation URL to the HTTP equivalent of it. Then publish it. It will put the files on your VM (assuming FTP is enabled on both sides), and the HTTP link should work.

By the way, you can also host your deployment in Azure blob storage. It is dirt cheap, and you can use something like Cerebrata Cloud Storage Studio or even write your own code to publish it (which I did). If you do this, then it will work even if you need to replace your VM or redeploy it or the VM becomes unavailable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

here is a reference to Avkash Chauhan's blog post explaining in detail How to deploy ClickOnce Application using Windows Azure Storage in very simple steps?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/05/09/how-to-deploy-clickonce-application-using-windows-azure-storage-in-very-simple-steps.aspx

He also gives an code example of a windows form (using Wpf) that he shows how to deploy on azure using one click deployment.

hope this helps

Comment: Dear Vishal i have created a public azure storage blog as specified by the link and tried to publish the application. But i am getting and error as given below. Failed to connect to 'http://***/***/' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site 'http://***/***'. The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed. If FrontPage Server Extensions are installed, this error can occur because the _vti_bin virtual directory is not marked as executable.   1